# Handling Duplicate Columns in Pandas DataFrame constructor from SQLAlchemy Join

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I know that `read_csv` has `mangle_dup_cols` but how can I do the same from a sql join in sqlalchemy after issuing:

```
pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall(), columns=result.keys())
```

which gives me an error when using `df.info()` because of dupe col names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own helper function which mangles column names. The code below I copied from the [`io.parsers._infer_columns`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L1535):

```
def mangle_dupe_cols(columns):
    counts = {}
    for i, col in enumerate(columns):
        cur_count = counts.get(col, 0)
        if cur_count > 0:
            columns[i] = '%s.%d' % (col, cur_count)
        counts[col] = cur_count + 1
    return columns

pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall(), columns=mangle_dupe_cols(result.keys()))
```

Comment: A little more intense than I was hoping but this is really cool. --thanks.